# Unnecessary stuff in animation

Tags: animation, game-engine, rigging, bones

I've never rigged a character so bare with me in what I am gonna ask.
I've been given a rigged character with animations. It works fine. I want to clean it up a bit by deleting things I don't need. Here is the image of the objects:

[image]

I guess I should not delete anything in the rig hierarchy, but can I delete all the ik/fk objects since the rig has been made and the animations are done ? If not what can I delete? If nothing, can I somehow bake the animations (I think I've heard it somewhere) and delete things I don't need after? And what things would those be?

Comment: why not give it a try and don't save if it messes things up?

Comment: Cause it might not cause a short-term problem but something I will find later on when it is too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those objects are labeled in a way that suggests they are shape widgets for the bones. Without these, the bones will look like the normal octahedral shapes (or however your armature is displayed). You could delete them if you *really* wanted to, but it's easier for those working on the file if you don't, especially us animators. It's very easy to get lost in a complex rig.

I would just parent them under an empty to clean up the outliner, if that's what you're really after.

The only parts I *would* delete are the lights, because those should be done in a separate file after animation is complete.

Comment: Yup a simple parenting covers me. I hope I won't see any problem in the future, thanks for the info!

Comment: You shouldn't need to worry about that. The bone shape is specified internally with a unique object ID, so no matter the hierarchy, it will always specify that object. You'll be fine.